# IHTMLEventObj::put_keyCode fails in IE9 RC

Tags: c++, internet-explorer-9, bho, ihtmldocument2

I have an IE BHO created over 3 years ago that uses IHTMLEventObj::put_keyCode function. This function has worked as documented in IE6, IE7 and IE8. However, when testing with IE9 RC it no longer works as documented. The function is called the same way and the result is S_OK, but the key does not show up in the input field. The call is being made in the DISPID_HTMLELEMENTEVENTS2_ONKEYPRESS even of my Invoke() function.

I found someone with a similar problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/abcbaffd-ed8a-45b8-840b-8ad8d7d10081, however for some reason I am not able to view the issue. I was able to view it using google cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3OkEceoi6jwJ:social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/abcbaffd-ed8a-45b8-840b-8ad8d7d10081+put_keyCode+IE9&cd=1&hl=pt-BR&ct=clnk&gl=br&source=www.google.com.br.

Any help would be greatly appreciated this is a critical issue that needs to be addressed asap.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
Here is some code, but wanted to stress, that this code works perfectly in IE6, IE7 and IE8. In IE9, it returns S_OK, but the key is not changed.

```
BOOL CToolBandObj::InvokeElementOnKeyPress (    DISPID dispidMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags,
                                            DISPPARAMS* pDispParams, VARIANT* pvarResult,
                                            EXCEPINFO*  pExcepInfo,  UINT* puArgErr)
{

    CComPtr<IDispatch> spEventObj;
    spEventObj = pDispParams->rgvarg[0].pdispVal;
    CComPtr<IHTMLEventObj> pHtmlEvent; 
    HRESULT hr = spEventObj->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLEventObj,(LPVOID*)&pHtmlEvent);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pHtmlEvent)
    {
        CComPtr<IHTMLElement>spElement;
        hr = pHtmlEvent->get_srcElement(&spElement);

        _bstr_t bstrTag;
        spElement->get_tagName(&bstrTag.GetBSTR());

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spElement)
        {
            LONG lKeyCode = 0;
            pHtmlEvent->get_keyCode(&lKeyCode);


            pHtmlEvent->put_keyCode(lKeyCode);
            pvarResult->vt = VT_BOOL;
            pvarResult->boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE;
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

We have filed a MSDN Case, they have found the issue, and last we heard from them were going to fix it.

Comment: what type of input field is it ?

Comment: could you post some sample code for your OnKeyPress event to show what you're doing in there ?

Comment: are you returning VARIANT_TRUE in pvarResult to cancel bubbling ?

Comment: Hello Maurizio, thanks for all the replies. I have updated my code snipped above. When i copied it, i removed some of the extra logic, and in doing so removed the final return code. Why do you think that it works perfectly in IE6, IE7, IE8 and not in IE9. This code is over 3 years old, and has worked great, and is in production. It's only failing in IE9. Thanks again!

Comment: If you look at the MSDN docs for the onkeypress event [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you'll notice the following: _In Internet Explorer 9, the type of event object depends on whether you use attachEvent or addEventListener to register the event handler. If you register the handler with addEventListener, an object of type KeyboardEvent is passed during the event. If you use attachEvent, the legacy event object is passed instead._

Comment: thanks for the tip Maurizio. Read this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769672(v=vs.85).aspx), and saw the diferent interfaces in IE9. But was not much help. IE9 is still backward compatible, and the `IHTMLEventObj::keyCode` by documentation should still work. I still think its an IE9 bug. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I agree, mcbros. I have the same problem in IE9 (not RC). In Javascript, I'm trying to update `event.keyCode`, and it doesn't actually update.

Comment: @David, this is quite strange. I have also posted a comment in the IE9 Feedback but have not gotten a response.  I also tried via JavaScript directly, and no luck. Anyone else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after opening a case and many weeks, a fix was released: [The IHTMLEventObj::put_keyCode function does not work in Internet Explorer 9 Standards mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2601254).

Thank you Microsoft!