# IE9 control keyboard buttons

Tags: button, keyboard, internet-explorer-9, keycode, preventdefault

I am trying to make form submit with TAB button.

It is working on FF, IE8, but on IE9 i cannot stop default action.

I found the answer here: [How do I convert Enter to Tab (with focus change) in IE9? It worked in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347857/how-do-i-convert-enter-to-tab-with-focus-change-in-ie9-it-worked-in-ie8)

But i cannot implement it.

Could somebody explain what "Fix" for ie9 i should add my script to work.

Thank you

```
function checkcode(e) {
    var keycode;
    if(!e)
        e = window.event;
    if(e.keyCode)
       keycode = e.keyCode;
    else
       keycode = e.charCode; 
    if(keycode == 9 || keycode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();            //Problem is here
        alert(keycode);
        return false;
    } else return true;
}
```

Comment: Anybody? This is useful for everyone :)

Comment: I tried using:         e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.preventDefault) { 
             e.preventDefault()
        } else { 
            e.returnValue = false
            alert('preventing');
        } but that does not work. I am thinking TAB button is processed before event. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that in IE onkeypress does not return keycodes for ctrl, shift or tab, onkeydown done the trick.